# Empowering Might radius

Tags: guild-wars-2

So I spec my guardian to precision damage and toughness. I noticed that some of my team mates are not getting might during the usage of [Empowering Might](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Empowering_Might) on my guardian honor spec maybe it's because of the stacking rule where you can only get 5 allied targets. Also another question is "what is the cooldown on it's effect?" because I don't think it would make any sense when a guardian just aoes a mob with 50% critical chance and the team would get a 25 might stack for 5 seconds

Comment: your wiki link shows this trait to have a 1-second internal cooldown. Doesn't that answer your second question?

Answer (score 1):

The "cooldown" for Empowering Might is only 1 second. This really only ensures you don't do exactly what you mentioned, and rack up a bunch of Might with a single ability.

Every time you get a critical hit you and allies within range gain Might for 5 seconds. That range is 240 *units*.

According to the official GW2 wiki: "Distance is defined in terms of units, which are essentially equivalent to inches"